# Update views global custom text programmatically

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Is there a way to update the value in a Global Text column of a view per row dynamically and programmatically? I want different values based on some logic for each row.

Please note, I am trying to avoid using a PHP filter column. I have tried the solutions as stated in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96192/how-to-alter-single-custom-field-value-in-views) or [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically).

Moreover, mine is a **csv export formatted** view using the [views data export module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export). So, the `template_THEME_preprocess_views_view_fields()` is not invoked. Can anyone also provide a hook where I can alter the values?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/7.x-3.x

Comment: This is for a table structured view. Mine is not one.